# IntelliJ: How can you have files of multiple languages in one module?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a scripts module containing both Ruby and Python scripts (as well as some other languages like Bash and Perl).  When I set the module to use a Ruby interpreter, then the editor is filled with errors when I try to open a Python file (since it's trying to interpret it as Ruby), but if I switch the interpreter to Python, then I have the same problem in reverse whenever I try to look at a Ruby file.

Is there some way to have it understand both Ruby and Python scripts in the same module?